# Rspec ArgumentError, object not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Why am I getting the error below?
When running a rspec test in console, I get the error that 'post' is unknown. yet the line of code that is failing is structured as such:

```
post :create, valid_params
```

as such:

```
it "assigns the new post to @post" do
  post :create, post: {title: RandomData.random_sentence, body: RandomData.random_paragraph}
  expect(assigns(:post)).to eq Post.last
end
```

Here is the error

```
  1) PostsController POST create assigns the new post to @post
 Failure/Error: post :create, post: {title: RandomData.random_sentence, body: RandomData.random_paragraph}

 ArgumentError:
   unknown keyword: post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails 5, then you need to wrap your `post` object within a `params` keyword argument, try with:

```
post :create, params: { post: { title: RandomData.random_sentence, body: RandomData.random_paragraph } }
```